# intermittent "incorrect checksum for freed object" error on CGContextDrawImage (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

I do experience a rare crash of my app - happens from time to time in a method where I convert a UIImage into an array of pixels so I can play with the pixels one by one (its a coloring book app).

My code for conversion is the following

```
init(image: UIImage){
    let imageref = image.CGImage
    self.width = CGImageGetWidth(imageref)
    self.height = CGImageGetHeight(imageref)
    // create new bitmap context
    let bitsPerComponent = UInt(8)
    let bytesPerPixel = UInt(4)
    let bitsPerPixel = bitsPerComponent * bytesPerPixel
    let bytesPerRow = UInt(self.width * bytesPerPixel)
    let byteCount = UInt(bytesPerRow * self.height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, self.width, self.height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

    // draw image to context
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(self.width), CGFloat(self.height))
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageref)
    // manipulate binary data
    let tmpPixelsArray: UnsafeMutablePointer<ARGB> = UnsafeMutablePointer<ARGB>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))
    self.pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<ARGB>.alloc(Int(byteCount));
}
```

and the crash happens at

```
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageref)
```

line, with an error message of "malloc: *** error for object 0x7aa3b000: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed."

There is no common replication pattern. Sometimes it happens on 10th iteration, sometimes on 5th and somtimes on 20th. Any idea how to debug this further?

Comment: The error message typically indicates that you either overwrote the end of allocated memory, or, as indicated that you wrote to memory that's been freed.  Since you don't have enough code here to reproduce the problem it's hard to say exactly where or how.  Nothing here is problematic other than the "manipulate binary data" part, which is really the most likely culprit.

Comment: David - thanks for your comment - looking into more details on how I "manipulate the binary data" guided me to solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1 was the creation of self.pixels table each and every time. I now have it behind a check for current array size.

Issue #2 was lack of memory management (destroy & dealloc) for this array.

Fixed piece of code - instead of:

```
self.pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<ARGB>.alloc(Int(byteCount));
```

I now have:

```
if (byteCount>self.previousMaxByteCount){
        println("ALLOC: \(byteCount)")
        self.previousMaxByteCount = byteCount
        self.pixels.destroy()
        self.pixels.dealloc(1)
        self.pixels = nil
        self.pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<ARGB>.alloc(Int(byteCount));
    }
```

I have also learned that the crash position reported by Swift/Xcode is not that reliable as in my previous Java experiences and the issue was not exactly in the line pointed out initially.

Comment: I used malloc instead of alloc and that was the problem. Thanks!